# What are the parameters in this LESS sprite shorthand specification?

Tags: css, less

I'm fairly new to LESS, and I have some code--which seems to work--for a sprite given to me that looks like this.  First a variable is defined as follows:

```
@my_img: 0px 105px 0px -105px 22px 22px 44px 150px 'sprites/sprite-img.png';
```

This variable gets used like this:

```
.someClass {
      .sprite(@my_img);
}
```

CSS output of this looks like this:

```
.someClass{
    background-image: url("sprites/sprite-img.png");
    background-position: 0 -105px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

What do the parameters in that variable definition indicate?  The last one (url) is obvious, and I believe from looking at the sprite that the 3rd and 4th ones seem to be the background position offsets (X and Y).  But what are the others?  What do each of the 9 elements in this variable specify?

1. ?
2. ?
3. horizontal position
4. vertical position
5. width
6. height
7. ?
8. ?
9. background-image url

Comment: No need for guesswork. Just find the `.sprite` mixin definition (it should be among less files you use) and look how it expands its parameters.

Comment: Ah, I see, I mistakenly thought .sprite was a part of LESS itself.  I'll dig around and see if I can find where it is defined.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I found the mixin definition...if you want to take what I put as an answer and make it into one of your own, I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be just fine if you accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on other answers helped make it clear that the `.sprite` usage is actually not part of LESS, but is a mixin definition, as follows.  So the extra stuff in the variable definition is not used in the sprite at all, but exists for other uses.

```
  .sprite-width(@sprite) {
    width: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[4]`;
  }

  .sprite-height(@sprite) {
    height: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[5]`;
  }

  .sprite-position(@sprite) {
    @sprite-offset-x: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[2]`;
    @sprite-offset-y: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[3]`;
    background-position: @sprite-offset-x  @sprite-offset-y;
  }

  .sprite-image(@sprite) {
    @sprite-image: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[8].slice(1, -2)`;
    background-image: url(@sprite-image);
  }

  .sprite(@sprite) {
    .sprite-image(@sprite);
    .sprite-position(@sprite);
    .sprite-width(@sprite);
    .sprite-height(@sprite);
  }
```